# Why Launch Page can not be fired up when reminder is displayed

Tags: windows-phone-7

I used the sample code below for testing. I could not figure out what went wrong. Appreciate if you can point out what I need to do on setting up or using Reminder.

1) ShowParams.xaml is setup

2) Below is the code to add reminder:

```
Uri navigationUri = new Uri("/ShowParams.xaml" + queryString, UriKind.Relative);

            Reminder reminder = new Reminder(name);
            reminder.Title = titleTextBox.Text;
            reminder.Content = contentTextBox.Text;
            reminder.BeginTime = beginTime;
            reminder.ExpirationTime = expirationTime;
            reminder.RecurrenceType = recurrence;

            reminder.NavigationUri = navigationUri;

            // Register the reminder with the system.

            ScheduledActionService.Add(reminder);
```

Thanks

Comment: What is happening when you run this? I'm not clear what the porblem is.

Comment: When I run the sample app and set up the reminder with URI to open the page, the notification of reminder will show up BUT you can not click the title and be transferred to the page of the URI. The notification can act as message dialog Box with the title and content but can not launch the Page even you set up URI. To enable the notifcation to transfer you to the URI in the reminder, you need to close the app. That means set up the reminder and close the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works. After playing around with the app, I realized you need to close it in order for it to work.
Thank all.