# WP Silverlight 8.1 App - Reminder not launching app when touched

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, reminders, win-phone-silverlight-8.1

Im having problems getting the Reminder notification to launch my App once it's touched. Through the [MSDN step by step guide and documentation found HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202965(v=vs.105).aspx), I know that, if the user does not touch any of the buttons (snooze/decline) but touches the popup itself, the Uri defined in the reminder should be opened inside the App. However, once I do that, not even the App itself is launched, let alone the specified Uri.

To make sure the problem wasn't on my App, I've created a new application and copied the exact code found on the page linked above, and while it does schedule a Reminder, once it pops up, touching it only makes it disappear, still not launching the App nor the specified Uri (which exists, yes).

I've already searched a bit around here, and even though I've found a couple of questions similar to what I'm asking ([such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683914/why-launch-page-can-not-be-fired-up-when-reminder-is-displayed)), it relates to WP 7, while Im having problems with WP 8.1.

The user in the previously mentioned question figured out by himself that one needs to have the app closed for the popup to launch it at the specified Uri. However, even doing so, nothing happens with me, both on the emulator and the device. I have even removed it from the suspended/previously used apps, but still nothing happens.

[I have also found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24300665/reminders-in-windows-phone-silverlight-8-1), but nobody answered, and I don't have enough rep to comment on his question asking if he found the solution :/

I'm using VS 2013 Professional Update 3, Windows 8.1 Pro 64 bits, The Windows Phone 8.1 SDK and Emulator and a Nokia Lumia 620 with Windows Phone 8.1 on it. My apps are Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1. If anyone wants, I can link to the binaries for the test app I've built, but it's really a copy & paste from the tutorial from the first link I mentioned.

If anyone could help me on this, I'd reeeeally appreciate, because I feel like I'm missing something really small and stupid, but can't figure out what. Other than that, it just seems like a bug on WP 8.1.

Thanks in advance, and sorry if it's an already solved question, but as you can see, I tried to find the answers and couldnt...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wanted to say, to whoever finds him/herself struggling with this problem, that I - sort of - solved this problem.
I got in touch with a Microsoft Developer Evangelist who told me that indeed, this feature was removed from the 8.1 API. He refused to admit it was simply a bug, even though he agrees on that fact that the "Uri" property still being there is confusing. I'm not sure whether to believe him or not on this matter (I still think it's a bug), but at least I found out the problem was not me.

In the end, the only viable solution was to convert the whole project back to WP 8.0. Since Visual Studio does not allow one to do it by simply editting the project file, I had to copy all files to a new project by hand. Luckily, there were no major issues while doing so. Now the "go to URI" behaviour works just fine!

Hope it helps someone :)